# Get selected location name from Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am creating Google Maps app in android I need to get selected location text like  "abc-Hotel" and "xyz-school" these are default hyper links in android google maps so i need to use like that i am getting location address from latlang using "Geocoder"   but i didn't get fav-location text.then how do I get selected location text.

Thank you.

google map working image

[image]

[i need to get location text like Rajendra swamy temple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1whg.png)

Answer (score 2):

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
Address address = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
Address obj = addresses.get(0);
latLng = new LatLng(obj.getLatitude(), obj.getLongitude());
final String addressText = String.format("%s, %s",obj.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? obj.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                            obj.getCountryName());
```

if you want more details in address then you can this methods.

```
obj.getAddressLine(0);
obj.getCountryName();
obj.getCountryCode();
obj.getAdminArea();
obj.getPostalCode();
obj.getSubAdminArea();
obj.getLocality();
obj.getSubThoroughfare();
```

works fine with my code..
hope this helps.

Comment: i am also using same this suppose if i clicking on "abc-school" then how to get that school name i got street address and postal code all these but i need to get map showing text every street having many land marks how to get that land mark text

Comment: that you may get it from obj.getAddressLine(0);

Comment: but i got null from obj.getAddressLine(0);

Comment: but i got null from obj.getAddressLine(0);

Comment: i used this one..            final String addressText = String.format("%s, %s",
                            address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                            address.getCountryName());

Answer (score 0):

Using the Geocoder class in the Android framework location APIs, you can convert an address to the corresponding geographic coordinates. This process is called geocoding. Alternatively, you can convert a geographic location to an address. The address lookup feature is also known as reverse geocoding.

Sample Example,

```
Geocoder geocoder= new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);

        try {

              //Place your latitude and longitude
              List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(37.423247,-122.085469, 1);

              if(addresses != null) {

                  Address fetchedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                  StringBuilder strAddress = new StringBuilder();

                  for(int i=0; i<fetchedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                        strAddress.append(fetchedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                  }

                  myAddress.setText("I am at: " +strAddress.toString());

              }

              else
                  myAddress.setText("No location found..!");

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html